# JBoss RESTEasy - show ALL path mappings

Tags: java, jboss, path, jax-rs, resteasy

Is there any way to dump out a list of mapped paths in RESTEasy? I've searched the  [documentation](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy/docs.html) and came up empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such functionality built in spec or in typical implementations. With some effort you can scan all your classes looking for @Path annotation and retrive mapped paths. A good start is this [article](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2008/01/14/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime).

In a bigger application people tend to keep all mappings in a configuration class , so no searching is needed.